# How do parenthesis work?

Tags: prolog

I wrote an algorithm and tried to implement it in Prolog, but what I found out is that the parenthesis do not work as expected: what is written in is not all done before exiting the parenthesis. Here is the code:

```
%1. If the first member of L1 is smaller than L2
%     A. If the first member of L1 is not equal to Last
%            Than: A.1 Add the first member of L1 to the first member of NL
%                  Begin recurssion on the resumption of L1, L2 resumption of NL
%                  and Last from L1.
%            Else: A.2  begin the recursion on resumption of L1, L2 with the
%                       first member and L3 with the first member.
%  2. If the first member in L1 is equal to the first member of L2,
%             Than: Start recursion on resumption of L1 and L2 (with its first
%                   member) and Last = *.
%  3. If the first member of L1 is bigger than the first membber of L2
%             Than: begin recursion on L1 with the first member, resumption of
%             L2 and Last = x. %(x != * only for debugging)
%  

                              */
make_list([X1|L1], [X2|L2], [X3|NewL], Last) :-
    (
        X1 < X2,
        (
            X1 \= Last,   %A
            X3=X1;
            make_list(L1, [X2|L2], NewL, X1) %B
        ),  %Why those parenthesis do not work as expected?

        ! %green cut
    );
    (
        X1=X2,
        make_list(L1, [X2|L2], [X3|NewL], *)
    ),
    !
    ;
    make_list([X1|L1], L2, [X3|NewL], *).
```

My question is how to make it work as expected and why does `B` not work once `A` is done? After all it is also in the same parenthesis, e.g.:

```
?- make_list([6,6,10,20],[10,25,30],L, -).
L = [6|_G849]  % (should be [6,20]).
```

EDIT1: make_list should find all members in `L1` that are not in `L2` and put them in NewL, while `Last` stores the last member in `L1` that was parsed.

EDIT2: no -> are allowed (this is howmework). If someone could show me how to express if then else in prolog, that could be great.

Comment: I didn't succeed to format the code appropriately. Sorry for that.

Comment: I've corrected the formatting. Please read [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/158402) to learn how to format correctly yourself in the future.

Comment: can you explain *in simple words* what this `make_list` is supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: `!/0` applies at the predicate level: here you'd want it to apply to some block level where blocks would be delimited by `(` and `)`. This notion of cut applied to blocks does not exist in Prolog. A cut will erase all encountered choice points up until its location in a predicate.

And instead of writing your code with a lot of `(;)/2` usage, consider introducing new clauses instead, for readability (precisely because we do not like parenthesis and figuring out `(;)/2` and `(,)/2` priorities):

```
c :- A; B.
```

can be written

```
c :- A.
c :- B.
```

It will quite often be better this way. Better to produce the code easily, better to maintain it, to read it and to expand it.

I didn't look at your predicate in depth or anything, just wanted to mention those two things.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that "green cut" of yours is not green at all; you have

```
( A ; B ), !
```

so on exit from `(A ; B)` the first time, if A succeeded, `B` won't be tried anymore - that is what the cut `!` is saying here: don't try any more.

If you want `B` to be tried too, remove the cut `!`.

If-then-else is:

```
ifte(A,B,C):- A, B.
ifte(A,B,C):- \+A, C.
```

We can spare us a `not` by using a `cut`,

```
ifte(A,B,C):- A, !, B.
ifte(A,B,C):- C.
```

About your code: we express `and then` with comma: `A,B`. To output the Last it's easiest to use a working predicate, with additional argument, "seen-last"; and in the base case finally the last seen and the output would be unified.