# How to bypass assigning an empty list to procedure's argument of the form [X|L]?

Tags: prolog

I have the following program:

```
% finds all members in sorted list L1 that are not in the sorted L2 
%   and puts them in NL
make_list(L1,L2,NL):-
    make_list(L1,L2,NL,x).
make_list([],_,[],_):-!.

% X represents the last value parsed from L1
make_list(L1,[],L2,X):-!,
    make_list(L1,[99999999],L2,X).

make_list([X1|L1],[X2|L2],[X3|NewL],Last):-
    (
        (X1<X2,
         X1 \= Last,
         X3=X1,!,
         make_list(L1,[X2|L2],NewL,X1);
         X1<X2,!,
         make_list(L1,[X2|L2],[X3|NewL],X1)
         )
    );
    (
        X1=X2,!,
        make_list(L1,[X2|L2],[X3|NewL],*)
    );
    make_list([X1|L1],L2,[X3|NewL],*).
```

My problem is that when the last values are the same (i.e: `?- make_list([1,2],[2],L).` ), the code doesn't work because of

```
make_list([X1|L1],L2,[X3|NewL],*).
```

and

```
make_list(L1,[X2|L2],[X3|NewL],*)
```

which passes a list with at least one variable (the 3rd list) to `make_list([],_,[],_)`. There is a comment that says what the program does. How to make the code do what it supposed to do?

I also asked a question about the same but completely not working code here: [How do parenthesis work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915425/how-do-parenthesis-work) .

Comment: Is this a homework/self-study?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
% finds all members in sorted list L1 that are not in the sorted L2 
% and puts them in NL

make_list(L1,L2,NL):-
    make_list(L1,L2,NL,x).

make_list([],_,[],_):-!.

% X represents the last value parsed from L1
make_list(L1,[],L2,X):-!,
    make_list(L1,[99999999],L2,X).
```

the problem here was that `NewL` was `[X3|NewL]` and when `L1` was empty, the `make_list([],_,[],_):-!.` was failed because `[X3|NewL]` cannot assign with `[]`

```
make_list([X1|L1],[X2|L2],NewL,Last):-
    X1<X2,
    X1 \= Last,
    NewL = [X3|NewL2],X3=X1,
    make_list(L1,[X2|L2],NewL2,X1),!
    ;
    X1<X2,
    make_list(L1,[X2|L2],NewL,X1),!.

make_list([X1|L1],[X1|L2],NewL,Last):-!,
    make_list(L1,[X1|L2],NewL,Last).
```

this next two cases is when `X1>X2`, `X2` is ignored anyway, `X1` ignored only if `X1=Last`

```
make_list([X1|L1],[_|L2],NewL,X1):-!, % X1>X2
    make_list(L1,L2,NewL,X1).

make_list([X1|L1],[_|L2],NewL,Last):- % X1>X2
    make_list([X1|L1],L2,NewL,Last).
```

Answer (score 2):

You should consider six mutually exclusive cases when solving this problem:

1. You run out of elements in both lists
2. You run out of elements in the first list, but not in the second
3. You run out of elements in the second list, but not in the first
4. Both lists have at least one element, and the head elements match
5. Both lists have at least one element, and the head element of the first list is smaller
6. Both lists have at least one element, and the head element of the first list is greater

These six combinations cover the rules that you need to write.

The first two cases can be covered by a single rule:

```
make_list([], _, []).
```

This means that if the first list is empty, there will be nothing to add to the output list.

The third case is simple too: if the second list is empty, the output is the same as the first list:

```
make_list(L1, [], L1).
```

Case number four is slightly less trivial: if the heads unify, drop them both at the same time, and solve a smaller sub-problem:

```
make_list([H|T1], [H|T2], NL) :-
    make_list(T1, T2, NL).
```

Case number five inserts the head of the first list into the output, and case number six skips the head of the second list:

```
make_list([H1|T1], [H2|T2], NL) :-
    H1 < H2,
    make_list(T1, [H2|T2], N2),
    NL = [H1|N2].

make_list([H1|T1], [H2|T2], NL) :-
    H1 > H2,
    make_list([H1|T1], T2, NL).
```

Note that this solution does not work as expected when the first list contains duplicates, and the second list does not contain duplicates of the corresponding elements.

Comment: I think I found a problem with that one, I hope to find more time tomorrow too explore it more deeply.

Comment: @VitaliPom I tried it with a simple example `make_list([0,1,3,5,7], [1,5], X)`, and it produced `[0, 3, 7]`. But if you do find an error, please do let me know of your test case.